# Is "Draw the line" an inclusive or exclusive term?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

When someone uses the phrase "draw the line", for example:

> I will do most household work, but I draw the line at laundry.

or

> I draw the line at Bill Nye when it comes to trusting popular scientist opinions.

do these phrases have an implicit inclusion or exclusion of the topic the line is being drawn about, or is it always contextual?

Comment: It's a very gray line.

Comment: It's both/either - and the ambiguity is typically important to its use. (Which I'm guessing is part of what @HotLicks suggested.) If you need to make clear which you mean, then you need to add something additional. The question should be closed as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard the phrase used exclusively, and most dictionaries seem to agree.

> draw the line: to say that you will definitely not allow or accept something

([Macmillan English Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/draw-the-line))

> draw the line: to fix a boundary **excluding** what one will not tolerate or engage in

(Webster's Unabridged)

Regarding your first example: obviously the person **will definitely not** do the laundry, they **refuse** to do it.

However, some dictionaries appear to be more ambiguous or broad in their definitions of the idiom:

> Set a limit on what one is willing to do or accept, **beyond which one will not go**

([oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/draw-the-line?q=draw%20the%20line))

Evidently the above definition implies it's OK to use the phrase inclusively as well. An example from the same source:

> We've always had a four wheel drive and we used to go camping - tent camping that is - but **I drew the line at that**.

Comment: But is this always the case, meaning the second example is incorrect usage of the phrase, or is there a secondary use where the term is inclusive, defining the limit of what the person will accept?

Comment: Personally, I've heard it used exclusively, but further research seems to show inclusive usage is OK, too. Updated my answer.